# Print string with special characters in Python

Tags: python, unicode, decode, encode, utf

I have this string:

```
"Binh Thanh, H\\u1ed3 Ch\\u00ed Minh, Vietnam"
```

I'm not really sure how it's encoded (unicode/utf-8...) but I know it's correspond to this one :

```
"Binh Thanh, Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam"
```

I would like to create a function that display it correctly

USAGE:

```
def display_characters(text):
    print(text)
    # .encode? .decode? utf-8? unicode?


display_characters("Binh Thanh, H\\u1ed3 Ch\\u00ed Minh, Vietnam")
```

EXPECTATION:

```
"Binh Thanh, Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `\\` which creates normal `\`, and is not part of unicode.

Python has special encodings `'raw_unicode_escape'` and  `'unicode_escape'` which help with some problems in unicode.

```
text = "Binh Thanh, H\\u1ed3 Ch\\u00ed Minh, Vietnam"

text = text.encode().decode('raw_unicode_escape')

print(text)
```

In this example works also `unicode_escape`

```
text = text.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

Doc: [Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

Answer (score 1):

Since your string contains `\\u` instead of `\u`, then the backslashes are escaped, so this string contains literal backslashes. If you write it as `"Binh Thanh, H\u1ed3 Ch\u00ed Minh, Vietnam"` instead, then the `\u` will be a proper Unicode escape.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a slash and use print. I think the extra slash is interfering:

```
print(u"Binh Thanh, H\u1ed3 Ch\u00ed Minh, Vietnam") 

Binh Thanh, Hồ Chí Minh, Vietnam
```